# FullCalendar v.2.2.6 'hasTime' undefined error when using addEventSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm currently trying to test out `FullCalendar` (version 2.2.6) `addEventSource`

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEventSource', cal_events_1);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', cal_events_2);
});
```

but I'm always getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
```

Both sources are hard coded and loading the calendar with either source loads the events successfully, so no date is incorrect.

```
var cal_events_1 = [
{
  events: [
  {
      title: 'event 1',
      start: '2015-01-04',
      color: 'tomato'
  },
  {
      title: 'event 2',
      start: '2015-01-09'
  }],
  color: '#55B2DA',
  textColor: '#3c3c3c'
},
{
  events: [
  {
      title: 'event 3',
      start: '2015-01-06'
  },
  {
      title: 'event 4',
      start: '2015-01-07'
  }],
  color: 'rgb(255, 162, 71)',
  textColor: '#3c3c3c'
},
{
    events: [
    {
        title: 'event 5',
        start: '2015-01-09'
    },
    {
        title: 'event 6',
        start: '2015-01-12'
    }],
    color: 'rgb(91, 228, 118)',
    textColor: '#3c3c3c'
}];

var cal_events_2 = [
{
  events: [
  {
      title: 'event 1',
      start: '2015-01-04',
      color: 'tomato'
  },
  {
      title: 'event 2',
      start: '2015-01-09'
  },
  {
      title: 'event 3',
      start: '2015-01-09'
  }],
  color: '#55B2DA',
  textColor: '#3c3c3c'
},
{
    events: [
    {
        title: 'event 4',
        start: '2015-01-09'
    },
    {
        title: 'event 5',
        start: '2015-01-12'
    }],
    color: 'rgb(91, 228, 118)',
    textColor: '#3c3c3c'
}];
```

Loading the calendar:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventSources:  cal_events_1 // or cal_events_2
});
```

The error is displayed only when calling `addEventSource`. I'm not sure what's wrong exactly.

**UPDATE**

I know the documentation of [`addEventSource`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) and [`removeEventSource`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/) mention using an array as a source but it looks like it does not work, `cal_events_1` and `cal_events_2` are both an array of objects. Using an object worked:

```
var my_events = {
  events: [
    {
      title: 'event 1',
      start: '2015-01-04',
      color: 'tomato'
    },
    {
      title: 'event 2',
      start: '2015-01-09'
    },
    {
      title: 'event 3',
      start: '2015-01-09'
    }
  ],
  color: '#55B2DA',
  textColor: '#3c3c3c'
};

$('button').click(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', my_events);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need the end time.

try this:

```
var my_events = {
  events: [
    {
      title: 'event 1',
      start: '2015-01-04',
      end: '2015-01-06',
      color: 'tomato'
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that error mostly for wrong data structure for event(s), null data for 'start' or 'end'  property or invalid date format in source data.

Answer (score 0):

addEventSource doesn't really accepts array. My advise is to iterate over cal_events_1 or cal_events_2 to have something like this after each iteration:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', {
    events: [
    {
        title: 'event 5',
        start: '2015-01-09'
    },
    {
        title: 'event 6',
        start: '2015-01-12'
    }],
    color: 'rgb(91, 228, 118)',
    textColor: '#3c3c3c'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm passing my **in time** and **out time** from **database**. I have fixed this error by specifying the **in time** as **start** and **out time** as **end** because the **FullCalender.js** checks for the  in time and out time with that variable also I forgot to add **semicolon** .
for GenerateCalender function.This is my code-

```
var event_array = [];

                    var selectedEvent = null;
                    FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                    function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                        events = [];
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/GetEvents",
                            data: "",
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("success");

                                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                                    event_array.push({
                                        userid: v.UserId,
                                        start: moment(v.LoginTime),
                                        //end: moment(v.LogoutTime)

                                        //start: moment(v.start),
                                        end: v.LogoutTime != null ? moment(v.LogoutTime) : null
                                        //color: v.themecolor,
                                        //allday: v.isfullday
                                    });

                                })

                                GenerateCalender(event_array);
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                alert('failed');
                            }
                        })
                    }
 function GenerateCalender(event_array) {
 $('#calender').fullCalendar({

                            events: event_array

                        });
}
```