# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using `fullCalendar` in order to display some events in a calendar.

I'm first fetching the events with AJAX and then giving it to `fullCalendar` like below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  getEvents();

});

function getEvents(){

  // Récupération des infos serveur
  var server_dns = $("#server_dns").html();

  // Envoi de la requête
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", server_dns+"/event");
  xhr.send("");

  // Attente de la réponse
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {

      // Réponse correcte
      if(xhr.status == 200){

        console.log(xhr.responseText);

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          events: [
            //{title  : 'event1',start  : '2017-05-28T12:30:00'},{title  : 'event2',start  : '2017-05-29T12:30:00'},{title  : 'event3',start  : '2017-08-30T12:30:00'},
            xhr.responseText
          ]
        });
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
>     at normalizeEventTimes (fullcalendar.js:12634)
>     at normalizeEventDates (fullcalendar.js:12614)
>     at assignDatesToEvent (fullcalendar.js:12605)
>     at buildEventFromInput (fullcalendar.js:12589)
>     at fullcalendar.js:12180
>     at Function.map (jquery-3.1.1.js:457)
>     at buildEventSource (fullcalendar.js:12179)
>     at Array. (fullcalendar.js:11835)
>     at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:368)
>     at Calendar_constructor.EventManager (fullcalendar.js:11832)

I think my JSON is well formatted because the console gives me output:

```
{title: 'test',start: '2017-05-26T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-06-02T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-06-09T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-06-16T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-06-23T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-06-30T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-07-07T12:13:00'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-07-14T12:13:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-04-22T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-04-29T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-05-06T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-05-13T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-05-20T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-05-27T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-06-03T22:22:00'},{title: 'Test2',start: '1995-06-10T22:22:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-05-27T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-06-03T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-06-10T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-06-17T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-06-24T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-07-01T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-07-08T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-07-15T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST3',start: '2017-07-22T12:00:00'},{title: 'TEST4',start: '2018-12-10T10:10:00'},{title: 'TEST4',start: '2018-12-17T10:10:00'}
```

Comment: `xhr.responseText` is already an array of objects from the look of it. Remove the `[ ]` next to `events:` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried but i got this error : jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 GET http://localhost:8080/sport_webapp/%7Btitle:%20'test',start:%20'2017-05-26T…20'2018-12-17T10:10:00'%7D?start=2017-04-30&end=2017-06-11&_=1495912388657 404 () I think it is considering as a JSON event source and trying to retrieve data

Comment: you need to parse the json string to array. The ajax could be simplified using `$.getJSON()` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**9th EDIT** *(!)*

`xhr.responseText` returns **ONE** string...
And FullCalendar expects an [array of objects](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/).

So just placing the string result from `xhr` withing square brackets `[]` is not enought.
It produces an array of length = 1 (one string).

The solution is to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) this string in order to separate each data parts that we'll use to create some objects.

Here the `|` has been used as a separator, since comas `,` are already used in the data.
This can be any chracter which is not present in the data received.

Then, using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse) in a loop through the array created by `split()`, we create the objects... And put them back in an array.

This last array will finally be passed to the `event` option of FullCalendar.

```
// Waiting Ajax response.
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {

    // Response OK.
    if(xhr.status == 200){

      // Visually check the response in console.
      console.log(xhr.responseText);

      // Split data.
      var splitted = xhr.responseText.split("|");

      // Create objects.
      var event_array=[];
      for(i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){

        // Push objects in the final array.
        event_array.push(JSON.parse(splitted[i]));
      }

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: event_array           // Event are correctly passed to FullCalendar.
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If you dare reading the below comments, you'll see all debuging steps which lead to this working answer.
;)

Comment: I have already tried a lot of combination but i got the same error (even if i add Z at the end of the date) moreover in the documentation it is specified that date must be ISO8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 but in some examples it is not (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/). Thanks for helping

Comment: Haa... I found it this time!!! Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932923/2159528)... You have no **end** datetime in your json. This is the problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry but my date is well formed because the console.log give that right now : {title: 'test',start: '2017-05-26T12:13:00Z'},{title: 'test',start: '2017-06-02T12:13:00Z'} ... I 've checked the date here http://jsfiddle.net/wq7tjec7/14/ and i'ts a valid date. Otherwise i've checked the entire json value here : https://jsonlint.com/ and it's not correct. Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Looking at the documentation the "end" is optional  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ . But i've tried with the end but it change nothing. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Okay... But I would try with some end date just to test. Maybe they say it is optionnal because it could be a full day event. But since you specify a time, It isn't so....

Comment: When i put an event manually it works : events: [
          {
            title: 'event 1',
            start: '2015-01-04',
            end: '2015-01-06',
            color: 'tomato'
          },
        ]

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/brv5OvWA0.png (look so smart with the reverso tab opened =)

Comment: Well, when i manually paste the console output directly in the JS file it's work but when i just put xhr.responseText i go the error.

Comment: try: `console.log( typeof( xhr.responseText );` for fun... If it isn't "string"... Try `JSON.stringify( xhr.responseText )` inside the event brackets... ;)

Comment: I think [xhr.responseText] is an incorrect syntax.EDIT : that's a string for sure

Comment: But look ok according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Yes. I have to convert my JSON String to an array cause console.log([xhr.responseText]) give me an array which length is 1

Comment: Haaa!!! This is ONE string. Well, You found the problem! Just split it at the `,` ;)

Comment: I have a string and i need an array of that https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

Comment: I finaly got the array by changing the separator of items by '|' (cause the coma is the separator for items and for fields). But i always got the same horrible error. Maybe i need to loop over the array cause it's an array of string and convert to a JSON object using JSON.parse ?

Comment: Wohoo i finaly success

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i was working on this error for more than 4 hours now. I owe you one.

Comment: Just accept the answer (if there is no error in it). I will improve the explanations for future readers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Final code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    getEvents();

});

function getEvents(){

    // Récupération des infos serveur
    var server_dns = $("#server_dns").html();

    // Envoi de la requête
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", server_dns+"/event");
    xhr.send("");

    // Attente de la réponse
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {

            // Réponse correcte
            if(xhr.status == 200){

                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var splitted = xhr.responseText.split("|");
                var event_array=[];
                for(i=0; i < splitted.length  ;i++){
                   event_array.push(JSON.parse(splitted[i]));
                 }
                console.log(event_array);

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    /* events: [
                            {
                              title: 'event 1',
                              start: '2017-05-26T12:13:00Z',
                              end: '2017-05-26T12:13:00Z',
                              color: 'tomato'
                            },
                          ]
                    */
                    events:  event_array
                });
                }

        }
    }
}
```